# How do you make re.sub() understand unicode?

Tags: python

You need to remove/replace any single German character, for example `ü`.

```
import re
re.sub(r'^\w{1}$', '', u'ü', re.U)
> u'\xfc'
```

The above code does not work but why if:

> **re.U**, 
>   **re.UNICODE**
>   Make the \w, \W, \b, \B, \d, \D, \s and \S sequences dependent on the Unicode character properties database. Also enables non-ASCII matching for IGNORECASE.

Comment: You probably shouldn't replace international characters in that way. There are better solutions, like the `unidecode` module or even `str.translate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.sub()` takes `flags` as the 5th argument, not the 4th. The 4th is `count`. This will work:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^\w$', '', u'ü', flags=re.U)
u''
```

Comment: @Novaterata: if it is for human consumption, why replace it in a way that will change or destroy meaning? use `unidecode`. If it is not for human consumption, why do you have to replace it at all? if you want to replace one and only one specific character, why use `re.sub` instead of `.replace()`?. if you want to replace more than one, why use repeated `.replace()` instead of `.translate()`? there is almost always a better way than regex. it depends on the context, but the OP didn't give us any (and was on the wrong track in any case).

Comment: @Novaterata: question and answer are offtopic enough as they are.

Comment: Honestly, python2.7 docs should stress the use of `flags` word because it is also erroneously used in the docs hence the constant confusion.

Comment: @minerals: where? i can't find it

Comment: @hop take a look at `re.VERBOSE` paragraph, there is `re.X` example which is used without `flags` as a second arg. Other examples are correct though but still. It should be explicitly said somewhere.

Comment: @minerals: what do you mean? `re.compile()` takes flags as second argument and that example is correct. how this works is "explicitely said" in the tutorial, 4.7.2. we can't repeat that whenever there is a function defined in the documentation.

Comment: @hop I see, well still, I seldom go to python docs just because I don't like how they are organized and the examples provided that is why I often skip through and that is why I often miss the important things not for the first time. Ruby docs are an excellent example of how to write succinct docs for example. Just my humble opinion.